# Display related products based on 2 specific product attributes values in WooCommerce

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I am looking for solution to display related product by multiple product attributes. I've tried *"[Display Related products for a specific product attribute value in single product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49961446/3730754)
"* StackOverFlow answer code, but it works only for **one** product attribute value.

How to make the same, but for **two product attributes** values?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: As the code that you tried to use come from StackOverFlow, this question should be asked also in StackOverFlow instead and deleted here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for($i=0; $i<count($attribute); $i++){
    $attribute[$i] = sanitize_title('pa_' .$attribute[$i]);
}

$terms = wp_get_post_terms(
'taxonomy' => $attribute
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried like this? sending $terms = wp_get_post_terms('taxonomy' => array('color','color2','color3')); check if it works and change the loop as per

Comment: When i'am trying like $terms = wp_get_post_terms('taxonomy' => array('color','color2','color3')); i've got server error 500 - expected )

Comment: Hey Parikshit Parab, nice code. Your answer is off to a good start. Please consider explaining how and why this code solves the problem so others can learn from it. Check the [guide to answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for further advice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not that simple using the related products functionality itself, but here is my code that selects related products by category + by color (product attribute). I have replaced default related products loop with a `[product]` shortcode. It's not perfect, but it works.

First of all you need a function that returns term slugs by specified taxonomy and product id. I have just tweaked native WooCommerce function `wc_get_product_term_ids`

```
public function my_get_product_term_slugs( $product_id, $taxonomy ) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy );
    return ( empty( $terms ) || is_wp_error( $terms ) ) ? array() : wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' );
}
```

Then I have used this function inside the main function that returns the product shortcode.

```
function my_get_custom_related_products( $product, $limit = 4 ) {
    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    $categories = implode( ', ', my_get_product_term_slugs( $product_id, 'product_cat' ) );
    $colors = implode( ', ', my_get_product_term_slugs( $product_id, 'pa_color' ) );

    return do_shortcode( '[products attribute="color" terms="' . $colors .  '" category="' . $categories . '" orderby="rand" limit="' . $limit . '"]' );
}
```

And then you call this function (with echo) on anywhere you want. I have replaced the related loop with this function. I also used `orderby="rand"` inside that `[product]` shortcode, to get random results after every reload. Of course you can move the the attribute taxonomy name to function parameters to have more control, but I hope this will help you.

I have tried to somehow tweak the native WC related products query, but it was time consuming so I have decided to go with the shortcode approach.